# Flask import local file

Tags: python, flask

I had the following issue with my flask application. I have the following file structure as follows. It seems the internal file include is not working. Can anyone please help me to sort out the issue. I am bit new to python and flask.
`app.py, db.py, blacklist.py` all are only in the root directory.
=====app.py=====

```
import flask
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager

from db import db
from blacklist import BLACKLIST

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return "<h1>Api Testing</h1><p>This is just testing endpoint.</p>"

app.run()
```

====db.py====

```
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy()
```

====blacklist.py====

```
BLACKLIST = set()
```

```
flask.cli.NoAppException
flask.cli.NoAppException: While importing "xxxxxxx.app", an ImportError was raised: Traceback (most recent call last): File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 240, in locate_app __import__(module_name) File "/Users/xxxxx/Documents/Vhosts/xxxxx/app.py", line 5, in <module> from db import db ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'db'
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, you should wrap you `app.run()` call inside a *main* block, otherwise the server will try to start even if you are only importing the object (which is what the Flask CLI does with you call `flask run`). The reasoning behind this has been covered [extensively elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)

```py
import flask
from flask_restful import Api
from flask_jwt_extended import JWTManager

from db import db
from blacklist import BLACKLIST

app = flask.Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def home():
    return "<h1>Api Testing</h1><p>This is just testing endpoint.</p>"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

That may solve your issue, however you should update your post to include the contents of your other files `db.py` and `blacklist.py` too. In your error message there is a mention of the `db` module, and without that there is nothing else to offer.

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I have updated my post as per your request. But still I am getting above error after updating.

Comment: I would cosign the advice of @dave-w-smith and make your module names more distinctive, there's a chance that Flask thinks that `db` is referring to something other than your file. Try changing the name and trying again.

Comment: it worked when I run the application like the following.
/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python3.7 /Users/xxxx/Documents/Vhosts/xxxxx/app.py

Comment: It goes without saying that you should be inside of your working directory when trying to call a package (by providing an absolute path you are accomplishing the same thing) so if you were not inside the `xxxxx` folder before, that's where your problem was coming from.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Yes finally understood that. @vulpxn Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When you're getting started, you can avoid a lot of problems by keeping your names distinct. In this case, instead of

```
from db import db
```

rename your file, and do something like

```
from mydb import db
```

Then, once you have something working, take things step-by-step, noting where things stop working, and use that an an excuse to explore how Python handles namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

I solve this problem using terminal as follows :

```
$export FLASK_APP=app
$flask run
```

Due to .py extension this problem was occurred.